# How to input our values in our two-input-neural network?

Tags: python, input, keras, neural-network

Here is my neural network :

[image: My neural network]

The input for input_3 is an image associated to a vector of float values in input_4.

What I want is to input these two values (image for input_3 and vector for input_4) in my neural network.

I code with Keras library. How can I do ?

**EDIT :**

This is what I thought and it works :

```
 model = Model(inputs=[input_image, input_vector], outputs = output)
 model.fit([image, vector], y, BATCH_SIZE,  NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Comment: You should include your code, you already have a model, and just need to call fit on it with the right parameters.

Comment: I edit the question now and it works

Comment: Include code in your question, not as comment, you can always edit your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a named `Input` layer for each of your inputs.

You find example code in  [Keras' getting started guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) under "Multi-input and multi-output models".